# Eclipse CDT / GDB error : Undefined maintenance set command: "python print-stack off". Try "help maintenance set"

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, eclipse-cdt

I am running Eclipse 3.7 , CDT  6.0   On Mac 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard)

I really really wanted to pretty print vectors !!!

I built  gdb-7.5 (Configured for  "x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0". )
I buit  [pythonPrettyPrinter](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_can_I_inspect_the_contents_of_STL_containers.3F)

I changed the default GDB command, changed the .gdbinit location and tried to run the

BUT now the Eclipse CDT is giving this error :

```
Error in final launch sequence Failed to execute MI command:
 maintenance set python print-stack off Error message from debugger back end: 
Undefined maintenance set command: "python print-stack off". Try "help maintenance set". 
Undefined maintenance set command: "python print-stack off".  Try "help maintenance set".
```

This error is tracked [here:](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367788)
But it appears the latest CDT will NOT have this fix since the update date was post CDT-head release.

My question is,  did any one have any luck with what I am trying ?

Is there a known workaround for my issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working after three more steps

1. Updated CDT to 8.1.1
   http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/juno/SR1/eclipse-cpp-juno-SR1-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz
2. Created a certificate named gdb-cert
3. Signed the GDB
   http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin

Answer (score 4):

As stated by the link posted above by infinity, simply changing Process Launcher to "Standard Create Process Launcher" will do the trick!

Answer (score 2):

This link gives a easier solution:

http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_4b2169480101elvx.html

It worked for me.